# Count the number of \item in multiple enumerate environments

Tags: enumerate, count

I'm trying to automatically generate the total number of items in multiple `enumerate` environments, but somehow this approach does not work for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
There are \ref{lst:num1} ways how a parameter can be given:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item By a constant expression.
    \item By user interaction.
    \item From another database. 
    \label{lst:num1}
\end{enumerate}

\begin{document}
There are \ref{lst:num2} ways how a parameter can be given:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item By a constant expression.
    \item By user interaction.
    \item From another database. 
    \label{lst:num2}
\end{enumerate}

A simple addition of the two numbers does not work in latex: \ref{lst:num1} + \ref{lst:num2}

\end{document}
```

Is there any way that I could generate the sum of `\ref{lst:num1}` and `\ref{lst:num2}` in latex? Any suggestion would be apppreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler if you `resume` the `enumerate`? See the manual of `enumitem`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the command  `\getrefnumber{...}` provided by the `refcount` package to get expandable numbers, then add the two numbers together using a counter (`newcnt` here). Finally display the result using the command `\thenewcont`.

**UPDATE** after follow-up question.

`\setcounter` sets the counter to a value: a single number or the sum of any combination of numbers.

You can also add another number to it using `\addtocounter`.

[image: d]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcount}% \getrefnumber{...} <<<<<
\newcounter{newcnt} % added <<<<<

\begin{document}
There are \ref{lst:num1} ways how a parameter can be given:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item By a constant expression.
    \item By user interaction.
    \item From another database. 
    \label{lst:num1}
\end{enumerate}

There are \ref{lst:num2} ways how a parameter can be given:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item By a constant expression.
    \item By user interaction.
    \item From another database. 
    \item None of above. 
    \label{lst:num2}
\end{enumerate}

\setcounter{newcnt}{\numexpr\getrefnumber{lst:num1}+ \getrefnumber{lst:num2}\relax} % added <<<<<   

A "simple" addition of the two numbers  in latex: \thenewcnt \medskip

There are \ref{lst:num3} ways how a parameter can be given:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item By a constant expression.
    \item By user interaction.
    \item From another database. 
    \item None of above. 
    \item All of above. 
    \label{lst:num3}
\end{enumerate}

\addtocounter{newcnt}{\getrefnumber{lst:num3}} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<You can add    

Cumulative addition using \verb|\addtocounter|: \thenewcnt \medskip

 \setcounter{newcnt}{\numexpr\getrefnumber{lst:num1}+ \getrefnumber{lst:num2}+ \getrefnumber{lst:num3}\relax}

Or  adding the three numbers: \thenewcnt \medskip

\setcounter{newcnt}{\numexpr \getrefnumber{lst:num2}+ \getrefnumber{lst:num3}\relax}

While the last two add up: \thenewcnt   

\end{document}
```

If you have many environments enumerate in the document, a simpler template for keeping the subtotal would be

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcount}% \getrefnumber{...} <<<<<
\newcounter{newcnt} % added <<<<<
\setcounter{newcnt}{0} % initial value of the acumulator <<<<<

\begin{document}
There are \ref{lst:num1} ways how a parameter can be given:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item By a constant expression.
    \item By user interaction.
    \item From another database. 
    \label{lst:num1}
\end{enumerate}

\addtocounter{newcnt}{\getrefnumber{lst:num1}}

Total number of items so far: \thenewcnt \medskip

There are \ref{lst:num2} ways how a parameter can be given:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item By a constant expression.
    \item By user interaction.
    \item From another database. 
    \item None of above. 
    \label{lst:num2}
\end{enumerate}

\addtocounter{newcnt}{\getrefnumber{lst:num2}}% <<<<<   

A "simple" addition of the two numbers  in latex: \thenewcnt \medskip

There are \ref{lst:num3} ways how a parameter can be given:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item By a constant expression.
    \item By user interaction.
    \item From another database. 
    \item None of above. 
    \item All of above. 
    \label{lst:num3}
\end{enumerate}

\addtocounter{newcnt}{\getrefnumber{lst:num3}} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<You can add    

Cumulative addition using \verb|\addtocounter|: \thenewcnt

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great and straightforward. If I have multiple `enumerate` environments and need to add multiple `\thenewcnt`, is this still a viable solution? I thought `\thenewcnt` can store only one addition?

Comment: @Miao Cai Thank you for your feedback! `\setcounter` sets the counter to a value, then you can add another number to the counter using `\addtocounter`. 
The counter stores a single number that can be the result of a numeric expression.
Easier to show with a example. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest approach.  `enumi` is the first level counter, `enumii` is the second level counter, and so on.

You can use `\getrefnumber` (refcount of hyperref) to add labels together, but it takes two runs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcounter{enumtotal}

\begin{document}
There are \ref{lst:num1} ways how a parameter can be given:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item By a constant expression.
    \item By user interaction.
    \item From another database. 
    \label{lst:num1}
    \addtocounter{enumtotal}{\value{enumi}}
\end{enumerate}

There are \ref{lst:num2} ways how a parameter can be given:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item By a constant expression.
    \item By user interaction.
    \item From another database. 
    \label{lst:num2}
    \addtocounter{enumtotal}{\value{enumi}}
\end{enumerate}

\theenumtotal{} total items.

\setcounter{enumtotal}{\getrefnumber{lst:num1}}%
\addtocounter{enumtotal}{\getrefnumber{lst:num2}}%
\theenumtotal{} computed using labels.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. If I had 3 `enumerate` environments (let's say a, b, and c) and I want to do multiple additions (`a+b`, `a+c`, `b+c`, and `a+b+c`), is it still a viable solution?

Comment: You may need multiple counters, one for each combination.  When adding labels, you could reuse one counter multiple times..